# to_timestamp to match columns value and retrieve records from Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table in which i insert sysdate while inserting records, but when i try to retrieve the records I am unable to do so.

Insert to History Table

```
Insert into Hist_Table
(select stg.*,sysdate from live_table stg)
```

Select from History Table (No Error but No records selected)

```
select * from Hist_Table
where hist_insert_dt = TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-07-09 05:58:29','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

OR

```
select * from Hist_Table
where hist_insert_dt = '2019-07-09 05:58:29'::timestamp
```

But the below works

```
select * from Hist_Table
where to_char(hist_insert_dt,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') = '2019-07-09 05:58:29'
```

Not sure why the below gives time with an offset

```
select to_timestamp('2019-07-09 05:58:29','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

output is : 2019-07-09 11:28:29 not sure why it gives 11:28 instead of 05:58

I want to able to get the records with the below command

```
select * from Hist_Table
where hist_insert_dt = TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-07-09 05:58:29','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: You `hist_insert_dt` probably has some milliseconds other than `.000`

Comment: thanks, it had miliseconds, but with miliseconds too i am not getting any records      select * from Hist_Table
where hist_insert_dt =TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-07-09 05:58:29.5829','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS')